# Prove or refute: If $\pi_1(X,x_0)\simeq 0$ for all $x_0 \in X$, then $X$ is path connected

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Prove or refute: If $\pi_1(X,x_0)\simeq 0$ for all $x_0 \in X$, then $X$ is path connected

Let $x_0,y_0\in X \Rightarrow \pi_1(X,x_0)\simeq \pi_1(X,y_0)$, but I don't know more, or if it's true.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true. Let $X=\{p,q\}$ with $p\neq q$ be equipped with the discrete topology. The fundamental group depends only on the path-connected component the basepoint is in, so one has that $\pi_1(X,p)\cong 0$ and $\pi_1(X,q)\cong 0$ (each path-connected component is trivially contractible, as they consist of only one point), but $X$ is not path-connected.

In fact, this argument generalizes to any finite set with the discrete topology.